# Check two line occurring in a file using c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to check log using C# so need to see if the two line occurs simultaneously or not.
For example if the filename is `A213.txt`

and has following two line

```
Converting table AM014
Table 'AM014' (522 records) is converted
```

so need to console write line as `'the file was success'`.

But if the file contains something in between those, say

```
Converting table AM014
Not Found
Not Found
Table 'AM014' (522 records) is converted
```

I need console write saying `'the file was not success'`

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you have tried?

Comment: two consecutive lines (`Not Found \n Not Found`) will vary in file or it will remain same through out file??

Comment: It will remain the same through out the file @Prasadtelkikar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.ReadAllText(@"pathToYourFile").Contains(@"Converting table AM014
Table 'AM014' (522 records) is converted")
```

Notice the line breaker. or

```
File.ReadAllText(@"pathToYourFile").Contains("Converting table AM014\r\nTable 'AM014' (522 records) is converted")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! It really was because of the space. Not only there was \r\n but when I opened it with Notepad++, there was special character NUL due to which I had to use \n\x00\r\n to get the result

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex for this. The regex would be: `Converting table (\w+)\b\W+Table.+?converted`

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Converting table (\w+)\b\W+Table.+?converted");
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach(Match match in matches) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value); // The whole string that matches.
    Console.WriteLine("Table: " + match.Groups[1].Value); // Table name
}
```

Essentially the regex looks for a string starting with `Converting table <a word>` followed immediately by `Table <the shortest string of characters> converted`. The best part is that you get the name of table in second matched group, i.e. `match.Groups[1].Value`.

You can see how it works here: https://regex101.com/r/AJeVub/1

Answer (score 0):

how about checking the line count

```
var isSuccess = File.ReadLines(@"pathToYourFile").Count() == 2;
```